# Image upload to folder link to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to upload an image to my webpage. I am using Cpanel. i want to upload the image to specific folder and link to mysql table. but unfortunately image is not uploading to folder nor data is saving to mysql table.if i remove the image upload code then it is working. But same code is working well if i run through my laptop where image is storing to particular folder and data is saving to mysql table. dont know where i make mistake in my code to upload in CPanel folder. 
Below is my code and need your kind advice!

```
  <form name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="Save.php">
    <td width="90">Machine Name<br /></td>
       <td >
     <input type="text" name="Machine_Name" size="9">
      </td>
       <td width="90">Trim Image: <br /></td>
       <td colspan="3">
     <input type="file" name="image" size="20">
      </td>        
    </form>
```

save.php

```
 $Machine_Name=$_POST['Machine_Name'];

    if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo "";
        }else{
        $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
        $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"label_image/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
   $location="label_image/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(Machine_Name,location) VALUES('$Machine_Name','$location')
```

Comment: `Save.php`!=`save.php`

Comment: Sorry it was a typo mistake. it should be Save.php

Comment: another typo you have is the missing `");` at the end of `VALUES('$Machine_Name','$location')`. Either way, check for errors with PHP's error reporting and for your query. @ me if you want, I won't be keeping this tab open for long. Plus, why are you trying to execute through CPanel? Do you have permissions to do so? if on a hosted site, see if they let you do that. Otherwise, try it from an http call. Check your max upload settings also and that the right permissions are set for the `label_image` to upload to.